# Criteria for SELECT bla1, bla2 FROM foo

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

I want a criteria that only selects bla1 and bla2 from all attributes of a given domain

`Foo.findAll()` or

```
def c = Foo.createCriteria()
def results = c {}
```

have:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

results = List of *all* attributes of given domain foo

want

```
SELECT bla1,bla2 FROM foo
```

written as Criteria
def c = Foo.createCriteria()
def results = c {
  ???
}

Comment: So your question is? Seems like you already have the awnser?

Comment: ups my fault, edit above, thanks

Comment: Does your domain **really** have that many attributes that you need to worry about trying to optimize like this? If so, then maybe you need to decompose your object model a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use projections

```
def c = Foo.createCriteria()
results = c.list {
    projections {
        property('bla1')
        property('bla2')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more natural to use HQL for this:

```
def results = Foo.executeQuery('SELECT bla1,bla2 FROM Foo')
```

The returned value will be a List of Object[], so if for example bla1 is a String and bla2 is an integer you'd access the data like

```
for (row in results {
   String bla1 = row[0]
   int bla2 = row[1]
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now using namedQueries which works fine:

class Item {
    Product product
    String somethingShown
    String somethingHidden

```
static belongsTo = [product:Product]
static constraints = {
    somethingShown()
    somethingHidden()
}
    static namedQueries = {
        restrictedObj { item ->
                projections {
                    property('product')
            property('somethingShown')
        }
        eq 'id', item.id
}
```

}

querying for restricted items

```
Item.restrictedObj(item).list()
```

Now only one question ist left, how to restrict class connected with belongsTo. For example if Product has a namedQuery "restrictedObj" too. any way to use this in criteriea property?